# Three.js - Need help about static declaration and dynamic ArrowHelper

Tags: javascript, dynamic, three.js

I have an issue about 2 different code snippets for drawing a vector along direction defined by `directionVectorLocal` vector.

the first one :

```
var transportedVector = {
    coordLocal,
    arrowHelper,
    directionVectorLocal,
    directionVector
};

var arrowHelperTest = new THREE.ArrowHelper(transportedVector.directionVectorLocal.normalize(), originLocalBasis, 100);
camera.add(arrowHelperTest);
```

In this case, the arrow `arrowHelperTest` is well displayed on scene.

Now, the second one :

```
var arrowHelper;
var transportedVector = {
    coordLocal,
    arrowHelper,
    directionVectorLocal,
    directionVector
};

transportedVector.arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(transportedVector.directionVectorLocal.normalize(), originLocalBasis, 100);
camera.add(transportedVector.arrowHelper);
```

In this case, the arrow `transportedVector.arrowHelper` is not displayed.

Here, I have to declare "`var arrowHelper;`" just before defining `transportedVector` object because if not, I get a "`ReferenceError: arrowHelper is not defined`" error.

I would like to declare dynamically `transportedVector.arrowHelper` defined into `transportedVector` object and be able to draw it into scene. Solution may be easy but I am not an expert in Javascript.

If someone could see what's wrong, this would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: First: the code you've posted is incomplete/partial, so we can't really test it properly. What are the values of originLocalBasis and directionVectorLocal? Second: your ReferenceError is expected. You need to review/study the correct usage of Javascript Objects vs. Arrays. These aside, the code seems to work in my tests. Are you sure you're adding Camera to the Scene in the 2nd test? (this usage isn't common, but is needed if you're adding child objects to the Camera and want the children to be visible in the scene.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment to your original post. This code appears to work fine in my case:

```
var directionVectorLocal = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);
var originLocalBasis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var transportedVector = {
    arrowHelper: null,
    directionVectorLocal: directionVectorLocal
};

transportedVector.arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(transportedVector.directionVectorLocal.normalize(), originLocalBasis, 100); // <-- Note the length of the arrow must be greater than the zNear value of the camera, otherwise it won't be visible.
camera.add(transportedVector.arrowHelper);
scene.add(camera);
```